# Implement interface in c++/CLI which is IDisposable when used in C#

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I am writing a c++ CLI class library, which is used to make some native C++ library usable in C#.

It consists of an interface in C++/CLI

```
public interface class ISensor
{
    double GetValue();
};
```

An implementation in C++/CLI:

```
public ref class SomeSensor : public ISensor
{
public:
    SomeSensor ();
    ~SomeSensor ();
    !SomeSensor ();

    // Inherited via ISensor
    virtual double GetValue();
};
```

In C# I want to use this class within a using statement:

```
using(ISensor sensor = new SomeSensor())
{
   sensor.GetValue();
}
```

This does not compile with the error message:

> 'SomeSensor': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'.

If I use SomeSensor directly `using(SomeSensor sensor=...)` it will compile, but I need to go via the interface.

How do I add IDisposable to an interface in c++/CLI?

Comment: public interface class ISensor : public IDisposable { ... }

Comment: @HansPassant That was actually my first thought. Then I could not find a header for IDisposable and read that in C++ the idisposable interface is generated by the destructor syntax. But I can't add a destructor to an interface.

Comment: @HansPassant Got it. I have to write public interface class ISensor : public System::IDisposable. Thanks a lot.